# sed Command on BusyBox expects different syntax?

Tags: sed, gnu, busybox

I hope I phrased the question correct.
I have a script that makes use of 'sed' a lot. It works great on my ubuntu with the GNU 'sed'.
But when I try to run it on BusyBox it fails.
Is there a way to get the GNU sed on busybox? I am not a Linux pro.

Comment: Do you have sed installed in busybox?

Comment: 1) What version of Busybox? 2) What errors/unexpected output are you getting? 3) Can you give us an example of a sed operation that works with GNU but not busybox?

Comment: 1) BusyBox v1.19.4 2/3) This input `{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}` with `sed -n -e 's/.*"upload_id":\s*"*\([^"]*\)"*.*/\1/p'` gives the desired output (hhgJHflih753jDhhod) on my ubuntu but not on BusyBox

Comment: BusyBox v1.29.3 (2021-01-17 01:25:00 PST) multi-call binary on ESXi: `echo '{"expires": "Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:30:29 +0000", "upload_id": "hhgJHflih753jDhhod", "offset": 293876}' | sed -n -e 's/.*"upload_id":\s*"*\([^"]*\)"*.*/\1/p'` returns `hhgJHflih753jDhhod`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Busybox` iteself may have limited implementation of `sed`. You can copy the `sed` binary to some location and invoke it directly pointing it with a full path.

You may fix some incompatibility issues with replacing escapes that BusyBox builtin `sed` does not support, e.g. replacing the `\s` escape with `[[:space:]]` will solve the space-matching issue.

Comment: replace the `\s` escape with `[[:space:]]`. I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Serge ! Totally did the job! Although there are other locations in the script where replacing `\s` didnt help. If you post this as answer I'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: @tzippy As you removed your comment with your regexp I just added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how [`busybox`](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) works. The tool is one single executable that acts in different ways depending on the name (or subcommand) with which it is called. If you call a symlink `sed` pointing to the `busybox` binary (or `busybox sed`), the "sed" functionality will be executed.

To get GNU sed into a busybox environment, you have to remove the `sed` symlink to `busybox` and provide a GNU `sed` binary and the libraries it depends on. You can identify the libraries with the `ldd` command:

```
$ ldd /bin/sed
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7f78000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xb7f56000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7e0f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7e0a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f79000)
```

Comment: Oh I did not know that actually! Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I just replaced the sed from busybox by downloading the sed package with opkg. this one appearently is the GNU sed.